# How should I read Google calendar of other's account?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using "a1.@gmail.com" for example.
I want to read the calendar of other account "a2.@gmail.com" through Google Apps Script of "a1.@gmail.com".

I wrote and tried the script below:

`const calendar_id="a2@gmail.com";`

`const calendar=CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendar_id);`

`console.log(calendar.getName())`

Then I got the error below:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'getName' of null`

I come across the similar error when I replace "getName" with getEvents(,,) or others.

Before I try to read the calendar of "a2@gmail.com", I changed the setting of "a2@gmail.com" and added "a1@gmail.com" to 'calendar setting → share with specific people`.

Comment: Have you checked the `a1` account able to access the `a2` calendar? Check it with `CalendarApp.getAllCalendars()`: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getallcalendars

Comment: Thank you for your comment!
I realized why I couldn't read the calendar after I read the webpage you showed me and searched for a little.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to adding "a1@gmail.com" to 'calendar setting → share with specific person' of "a2@gmail.com", you have to check the gmail(a1) sent after this setting change.
Then you will find the mail whose title is "a2@gmail.com has shared a calendar with you". In the body of the mail, there is ***add this calendar***(URL) and click this.

Following this process, you need to make it sure that your calendar that you want to read in the script is listed in "My calendars" or "Others calendars", which is surrounded by the red line in the picture below.

[image]
Then you can read the calendar in the script!!